# JQuery how to reference JSON value

Tags: jquery, json

I'm getting a response back from a processor in this form. If I do console.log(data), this is the result:

```
{
"status":"No",

"errors":["Dummy Error msg 1","Dummy Error msg 2"],

"successMessages":["Dummy Success msg 1","Dummy Success msg 2"]

}
```

Either errors or successMessages could be null. I want to iterate through the errors and success messages (if any) to display them, but data.status, data.errors, and data.successMessages are undefined.

I can capture them with something like $.parseJSON(data.SuccessMessages),  which returns

```
Dummy Success msg 1,Dummy Success msg 2
```

but isn't there a way to reference them directly and iterate through them?

Comment: You can just use `JSON.parse` instead of `$.parseJSON`. All latest browsers have built in `JSON.parse`.

Comment: Try using `reponse.successMessages[0]`

Comment: What does your actual code look like? The options you're using to make the ajax call are relevant.

Comment: if you are using getting this as ajax response. you can specify the dataType in ajax as JSON so that you don't have to use pareJSON

Comment: Thanks! setting dataType: "json",  was the key. I would have thought the default "intelligent guess" would have recognized the return value as JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var obj = {"status":"No",

    "errors":["Dummy Error msg 1","Dummy Error msg 2"],

    "successMessages":["Dummy Success msg 1","Dummy Success msg 2"]};

obj['errors'].forEach(function(err, i){console.log(err);});
```